# Ошибка при генерации подписанного APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

При попытке собрать подписанный apk постоянно выходит ошибка:

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>
> Failed to read key mihail from store "/Volumes/yd/giftdep6.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Попробовал создать новый keystore с другими данными (штук 10 разных) все равно выходит такая ошибка. В сплывающем окне Android Studio создаю новый keystore и сразу отправляю на генерацию и все равно ошибка.

Comment: Ну оно пишет, что пароль вы указали неправильный. Попробуйте все сначала, точно следуя одному из способов [этой инструкции](http://dolbodub.blogspot.ru/2014/04/android-studio-apk.html)

Comment: я же говорю, я даже новый создаю, все равно так же

Comment: а как собираете АПК? через меню android studio, или через build.gradle?

Comment: @metalurgus - я нашел когда происходит проблема. Если я добавляю в свои gradle файлы эти строчки:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3' - в файл верхнего уровня. 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' - в файл нижнего уровня.

они используются для push. После добавления этих строчек проект не строится. Без них все ОК.

Comment: ну, попробуйте как минимум использовать стабильные версии, а не **beta**